# What's the meaning of the two file status after svn merge?

Tags: svn, svn-merge

In my trunk working copy, I run `svn merge -r 41324:41557 branch_url`, and getting the following output:

```
--- Merging r41325 through r41557 into '.':
U    KfClient\ctimclientapp.cpp
U    KfClient\util\utility.cpp
   C KfClient\chat\group_service\src\domain\group_member\groupkf.cpp
   C KfClient\chat\group_service\src\domain\group_member\groupkf.h
C    KfClient\resources\docs\version_log.txt
```

Why there are two status mark columns and what are they meaning? For example, the `C` may appear in the first column or the second column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `svn help merge`:

> Characters in the first column report about the item itself.
>   Characters in the second column report about properties of the item.
>   A 'C' in the third column indicates a tree conflict, while a 'C' in
>   the first and second columns indicate textual conflicts in files   and
>   in property values, respectively.